# Can someone help me with the GD library in windows?

Tags: php

I cannot get this to work on Wondows. There is a dll file bundled in the gdwin.zip file that I downloaded called "bgd.dll". I read that this file needs to go into the ext directory and then simply add / uncomment the library in the ini file. I've done that but I cannot get this working. Can someone please help? I'm on 5.2

---

This is the error message I'm getting. I have restarted the server.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files\\PHP\\ext\\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I renamed the dll back to its original name and now I am getting this error after I restart the server:

```
PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'bgd.dll'  in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Did you restart the server after the fact?

Comment: Hi Guard, yes.. restarted several times and nothing. I get this:          PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files\\PHP\\ext\\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Comment: PHP comes with the php_gd2.dll include (since 4.3 anyway),  so all you should have to do is enable it in the php.ini file. This page explains more http://www.libgd.org/FAQ_PHP but it looks like the file you've download isn't suitable for use with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

i just downloaded the php 5.2.11 zip from php.net and it has the php_gd1.dll in the ext folder already .. so u should just uncomment the line from the php.ini and that should be it. u dont need to get the gd lib seperatly.